# Why does NTFS for Mac and “About this Mac” show two different free space values?

Tags: macbook, storage

I cannot understand why these reports have a huge difference which is trying to report the same information for my MacBook Pro.

Here is what [NTFS for Mac](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/ntfs-mac/) shows:

[image: Report by NTFS for Mac]

And here is what I see via “About This Mac”:

[image: Report by "About This Mac"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check what Disk Utility says to get an accurate figure.
Different apps deal with the Purgeable space differently.

NTFS for Mac includes the Purgeable value & About this Mac excludes it.

[image]

Disk Utility tells you both...

[image]

If you're trying to re-partition, for instance to add Boot Camp, then it's the value in Disk Utility that is the important one - in this case the 410.91GB.

Comment: Thank you !!!. I get it

Comment: Welcome :) if you feel it answered your question, please click the checkmark to the left of the answer,  it lets future Googlers know that the answer 'worked'.

Comment: Get your bonus bro :))